# Using an external contract, how can you make it call a function on a target contract that requires a signature?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, erc-721, signature

I'm trying to create a contract that calls the following mintNFT function but one of the parameters it needs is a signature:

```
function mintNFT(uint256 _numOfTokens, bytes memory _signature) public payable {
    //emitted code
    (bool success, string memory reason) = canMint(msg.sender, _signature);
    //emitted code
}
```

What do I need to do to in my contract to pass in that signature? Or is that even possible using an external contract (not EOA)? Thank you!

Additional info. The only time it checks the signature is if it's on the whitelist in the following function:

```
function canMint(address _address, bytes memory _signature) public view returns (bool, string memory) {
    if (!whitelist[_address]) {
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(whitelistSigner, _address));
        bytes32 messageHash = hash.toEthSignedMessageHash();

        address signer = messageHash.recover(_signature);

        if (signer != whitelistSigner) {
            return (false, "Invalid signature");
        }
    }
```